# AWS Sagemaker studio Notebook asks username & PAT everytime I push or pull

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am pretty new to AWS Sage-maker, I was able to clone my github repo into my sagemaker studio notebook.Once I update my code within the studio notebook environment and use github terminal to push my changes it asks for username & PAT each time.

Where do i persist the username & pat within the sagemaker studio environment so that it doesnt ask for username and PAT everytime i push or pull new updates

I did do some research online , I see tutorials on how to link github repo to a notebook instance and not to studio notebook instance

Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research found that using git terminal I will be able to clone a repo using my PAT in the format as below :

```
git clone https://$GITHUB_PAT:x-oauth-basic@github.com/github_repo_name
```

`$GITHUB_PAT` = is the PAT from your github

`github_repo_name` = is the git hub repo you want to clone

I tried to push/pull after that it did not ask for username/pat